# Adding 6 TabSpec to single tabhost

Tags: android, android-layout

How can I add 6 tabspec to single tabhost?can i use any scrolling to tabhost?Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost 
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"  >
  <LinearLayout
       android:orientation="vertical"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="fill_parent">
  <HorizontalScrollView 
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:fillViewport="true"
       android:scrollbars="none">
  <TabWidget 
       android:id="@android:id/tabs"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
  </HorizontalScrollView>
  <FrameLayout
       android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
  </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

if want to scroll.

Answer (score 0):

The tabhost adjust themselve on the screen
.You can add them as

```
TabHost tabHost;
TabHost.TabSpec spec;
 tabHost=getTabHost()
 Intent intent;
   intent=new Intent().setClass(this, BirthDayTab.class);
 spec=tabHost.newTabSpec("artists").setIndicator("BirthDay",res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_artists)).setContent(intent);
   tabHost.addTab(spec);
```

Use it for 6 time or make a method to call it 6 time.